# why is @param and @return used inside laravel comments

Tags: laravel

I'm a beginner in laravel , and i recently came accross the below mentioned comments in a project ,

```
   /**
     *
     * @param $address, $type
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     *
     */
```

can somebody explain what is it?

Comment: It tells you what to pass to the method and what the output should be. This will make debugging easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@param** is the parameters that the function/method will handle, in that case, needing an *address* and then a *type*

**@return** means the data that you will receive after the execution of that function/method

Answer (score 1):

It tells you what to pass to the method and what the output should be. This will make debugging easier.